# Run testcontainers in github actions for unit tests

Tags: kotlin, gremlin, testcontainers, arcadedb

i am trying to use  testcontainers  for unit tests in github actions
here is my github workflow file:

```
name: 'CI-build'


on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'main'
      - 'master'
      - 'v-*'
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
      - reopened
      - synchronize
    branches:
      - 'main'
      - 'master'
      - 'v-*'
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up JDK 17
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: '17'
          distribution: 'temurin'

      - name: Run Tests
        uses: gradle/gradle-build-action@v2
        with:
          arguments: check -i
```

and my gremlin-driver connection code:

```
    private val cluster = Cluster.build()
        .addContactPoint("localhost")
        .port("mappedPort from testContainers")
        .credentials(user, pass)
        .enableSsl(false)
        .create()

    private val g = traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection.using(cluster, "g"))
```

i see following error during gradle task executing

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.remote.RemoteConnectionException: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.exception.NoHostAvailableException: All hosts are considered unavailable due to previous exceptions. Check the error log to find the actual reason.
```

and here log after startup arcadeDb container

```
  2023-07-23 17:37:38.015 INFO  [DefaultGraphManager] Graph [graph] was successfully configured via [./config/gremlin-server.properties].
    2023-07-23 17:37:38.022 INFO  [ServerGremlinExecutor] Initialized Gremlin thread pool.  Threads in pool named with pattern gremlin-*
    2023-07-23 17:37:38.040 INFO  [ServerGremlinExecutor] Initialized GremlinExecutor and preparing GremlinScriptEngines instances.
    2023-07-23 17:37:39.677 INFO  [ServerGremlinExecutor] Initialized gremlin-groovy GremlinScriptEngine and registered metrics
    2023-07-23 17:37:39.687 INFO  [ServerGremlinExecutor] A GraphTraversalSource is now bound to [g] with graphtraversalsource[arcadegraph[graph], standard]
    2023-07-23 17:37:39.688 INFO  [ServerGremlinExecutor] A GraphTraversalSource is now bound to [graph] with graphtraversalsource[arcadegraph[graph], standard]
    2023-07-23 17:37:39.709 INFO  [OpLoader] Adding the standard OpProcessor.
    2023-07-23 17:37:40.103 INFO  [OpLoader] Adding the session OpProcessor.
    2023-07-23 17:37:40.109 INFO  [OpLoader] Adding the traversal OpProcessor.
    2023-07-23 17:37:40.200 INFO  [GremlinServer] Executing start up LifeCycleHook
    2023-07-23 17:37:40.239 INFO  [GremlinServer] Executed once at startup of Gremlin Server.
    2023-07-23 17:37:40.244 INFO  [GremlinServer] idleConnectionTimeout was set to 0 which resolves to 0 seconds when configuring this value - this feature will be disabled
    2023-07-23 17:37:40.246 INFO  [GremlinServer] keepAliveInterval was set to 0 which resolves to 0 seconds when configuring this value - this feature will be disabled
    2023-07-23 17:37:40.317 INFO  [AbstractChannelizer] Configured application/vnd.graphbinary-v1.0 with org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1
    2023-07-23 17:37:40.359 INFO  [AbstractChannelizer] Configured application/vnd.gremlin-v3.0+json with org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0
    2023-07-23 17:37:40.360 INFO  [AbstractChannelizer] Configured application/json with org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0
    2023-07-23 17:37:40.364 INFO  [AbstractChannelizer] Configured application/vnd.gremlin-v2.0+json with org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV2d0
    2023-07-23 17:37:40.370 INFO  [AbstractChannelizer] application/json already has org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0 configured - it will not be replaced by org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV2d0, change order of serialization configuration if this is not desired.
    2023-07-23 17:37:40.459 INFO  [ArcadeDBServer] <ArcadeDB_0> - GremlinServer plugin started
    2023-07-23 17:37:40.461 INFO  [HttpServer] <ArcadeDB_0> - Starting HTTP Server (host=0.0.0.0 port=2480-2489 httpsPort=2490-2499)...
    2023-07-23 17:37:40.474 INFO  [GremlinServer] Gremlin Server configured with worker thread pool of 1, gremlin pool of 2 and boss thread pool of 1.
    2023-07-23 17:37:40.475 INFO  [GremlinServer] Channel started at port 8182.
    2023-07-23 17:37:40.647 INFO  [HttpServer] <ArcadeDB_0> - HTTP Server started (host=0.0.0.0 port=2480 httpsPort=2490)
    2023-07-23 17:37:40.651 INFO  [ArcadeDBServer] <ArcadeDB_0> Available query languages: [sqlscript, mongo, gremlin, java, cypher, js, graphql, sql]
    2023-07-23 17:37:40.652 INFO  [ArcadeDBServer] <ArcadeDB_0> ArcadeDB Server started in 'development' mode (CPUs=2 MAXRAM=2.00GB)
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please also show the code launching test containers?

Comment: Suspicious are: 1)` graph` variable seems to be used both as Graph and as GraphTraversalSource, see  "A GraphTraversalSource is now bound to [graph] ..." 2) JDK 17 is possibly not supported by TinkerPop (I failed googling this)